# React Native NavigationCardStackStyleInterpolator.forHorizontal undefined

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

When I try to run my React Native project on the iOS simulator and on my iPhone I keep getting this random error `undefined is not an object NavigationCardStackStyleInterpolator.forHorizontal`.

Have you had this error or know what may be causing it?

[image]

Also posted on Github: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/552

I believe it's related to react-native-router-flux

Answer (score 1):

Current 3.22.0 version of react-native-router-flux supports React Native 0.22 only, it is written in its README.

Comment: seems to be an issue with React native 0.22.2 as well.

Comment: Please use 3.22.0 version for react-native-router-flux

Comment: I'm using react-native-router-flux@3.26.10 with react-native@0.26.2 and I'm getting the same error :/